# Azure Data Factory Variable Not Accepting Arrays

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am trying to pass a number of variables into a copy activity. However, I keep on getting the error:

```
{
    "errorCode": "InvalidTemplate",
    "message": "The expression 'string(activity('MyLookup').output.value[0].companyId[item()])' cannot be evaluated because property '0' cannot be selected. Property selection is not supported on values of type 'String'.",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "Set variable1",
    "details": ""
}
```

[image]

My Variables are as follows:

[image]

The actual configuration for the Set variable 1 is:
[image]

[image]

Any thoughts on why I'm getting the error?

The settings of the Lookup activity 'MyLookup' is as follows:

[image]

The output of Mylookup activity is as follows:

[image]

Comment: Do you have 'First Row Only' seleceted on MyLookup Settings?  What does the output of MyLookup look like?

Comment: Hi Scott, 'First Row Only' is not selected. I have updated the question showing images.

Comment: maybe you have to wrap acivity('MyLookup').output with json function: json(activity('MyLookup').output).vale[0].companyId  But you cannot use companyId like an array because it is not one.  You probably need a Filter activity to filter to the object that contains the matching companyId.

Comment: Scott, do you mean something like this ```@json(activity('MyLookup1).output.value[0].data[item()])```

Comment: that will give you the first item in the value array, is that what you want?  I am guessing not now that I think about.  What is the ForEach running over - is it the value array?  If it is and you want the companyId of the current iteration that should be item().companyId I believe.  If that is not what you want you might need to explain better what you are trying to get.

Comment: Hi Scott, I'm strugging to detail exactly what I'm after .. anyway, I have an array as shown in the question. Lookup contains a number of company Ids. The plan is for the FOR EACH activity to loop through the Lookup activity and add the company id to the array with the parameter relativeURLs. Does that give more clarity?

Comment: yes, within the foreach you should be able to use item().companyId to get the companyId for each iteration.  Since the foreach must be running over the value array from the Lookkup what is passed to each iteration is something like {"companyId": "<value for this iteration>"} if that makes sense.

Comment: Sitll getting the error ```{
    "errorCode": "InvalidTemplate",
    "message": "The expression 'json(activity('MyLookup').output.value[0].companyId[item()])' cannot be evaluated because property '0' cannot be selected. Property selection is not supported on values of type 'String'.",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "Set variable1",
    "details": ""
}```

Comment: the right parentheses for the json function should be right after .ouput, not at the very end.  You war trying to convert the Lookup output from string to json so that you can get to the properties inside with dot notation.

Comment: Do you mean like this ```@json(activity('MyLookup1).output].value[0].data[item())``` ?

Comment: @json(activity('MyLookup1).output).value[0].data[item()] , you had ) and ] mixed up.  I suspect that will give you a different error where you have data[item()] though because item() is probably an object.

Comment: I'm getting an incorrect syntax with ```@json(activity('MyLookup').output).value[0].data[item()]```

Comment: My comment shows I expected that.  I think you need to try item().companyId and see if that gives you what you want which I am guessing you want the companyId of the current foreach iteration.  If that isn't it then you need to update your question as to what you are trying to achieve.  It doesn't seem like I can provide any other suggestions besides what I already have without better details.

Comment: What are you using in the `for each` activity `items` settings (over which array are you iterating)?

Comment: Hi Saideep, thanks for reaching out. These are the settings for the the For Each activity ```@pipeline().parameters.relativeURLs```

Comment: TBH, I may need to start this question again, with clearer details as @ScottMildenberger suggested. I think I might even be confusing myself.

Comment: can you try this `@string(activity('myLookUp').output.value[item()].companyId)`. `companyId` attribute has string values and hence index can't be used

Comment: Hi Saideep, with your suggestion I'm getting the following error  ```{
    "errorCode": "InvalidTemplate",
    "message": "The expression 'string(activity('MyLookup').output.value[item()].companyId)' cannot be evaluated because property '/apiCore/api/Metrics' cannot be selected. Array elements can only be selected using an integer index.",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "Set variable1",
    "details": ""
}```

Comment: I think more information is needed. I see you have relativeURL array (parameter) and companyId lookup output array. What is the actual requirement? Try to edit the question to provide with this information.

Comment: Hi Saideep, I agree, the question needs further clarification. I will add more details. Thanks

Comment: In the meantime, could you look at my most recent question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74445617/azure-data-factory-json-merge-operation-only-merges-first-two-rows

Answer (score 0):

Foreach Items property should be set as  :

`@activity('MyLookup').output.Value`

and the SetVariable which is inside the FE loop should

@item().companyid