# Azure Data Factory JSON Merge Operation Only Merges First Two Rows

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am attempting to merge multiple JSON files. For testing purposes, I am just attempting to merge just two JSON files. However, the results of the Merge only includes the first row of each JSON.

For example, if I were to merge the following JSON tables, see image(I know the image doesn't show JSON tables, but the actual JSON is too big to show here) the output would just show the first row of each table.

First Table

[image: JSON Table One]

Second Table

[image]

Output
[image]

You can see the output just shows the first row of each table.

My configuration is as follows:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I think this could an easy solution.

Your thoughts are welcomed

So, I changed my collection reference to the following:

[image]

I updated the Copy Activity as follows, but still getting the the first and second rows 4000 times:

[image]

I don't know why this keeps on failing for me.

The above is a preview of my json
[image]

I have updated my mapping as follows:

[image]

But I still keep only getting two rows:

[image]

There must be something simple that I'm missing....

Comment: `$['data'][0]['name']` is the issue here. The index `0` here is selecting only 1 element. Try using `data` as your collection reference and try to copy then.

Comment: Hi Saideep, I updated the question to show how I have changed the collection reference... that worked. However, now I'm getting the first two rows over 4000 times..

Comment: Try changing the source mapping to `['id']`, `['companyId']`, and so on and try.

Comment: Hi @SaideepArikontham, I changed source mapping as you suggested, see updated image, however, I'm still getting the first row and the second row over 4000 times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reproduced the above and got the below result.

These are my sample json files.

**Sample1.json**

```
{
"data":[
{
  "name": "Rakesh",
  "id": "1"
},
{
  "name": "Kohli",
  "id": "2"
}
]
}
```

**Sample2.json**

```
{
"data":[
{
  "name": "Laddu",
  "id": "1"
},
{
  "name": "Virat",
  "id": "2"
}
]
}
```

I got the same output when I did the mapping like below.

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

Give the mapping like below `import schemas-> advanced editor -> collection reference` and you can get the desired merging.

[image]

**Output json:**

[image]

Comment: Hi Rakesh, I have followed your suggestion exactly, see updated images, but I keep on only getting two rows.. I can't think where I'm going wrong

Comment: check the advanced editor in the mapping after importing schemas like above.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/xA87PIn.png mapped like this?

Comment: Yaaaaayyyy..... @Rakesh, it worked. Thank you so much mate. Appreciate it. I thought I was going to go crazy